# Уведомления в iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, уведомления

Добрый день

Работают ли Notification Content Extension на iPhone 5, 5c ?

У меня все отлично работает на 5s, SE, iPadMini2. Но UNUserNotificationCenter.current().supportsContentExtensions выдает false на iPhone 5c...

Answer (score 0):

[Документация от apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/2196946-supportscontentextensions) говорит что если данный метод вернул ***false*** значит устройство не поддерживает ContentExtensions. Та же по теме [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43190540/7117519)